# How to re-render Gutenberg component when object instance is available

Tags: javascript, block-editor, react, masonry

I'm working on a Gutenberg component that displays a grid of images using the core Masonry library (some code omitted for brevity):

```
const containerMasonryRef = useRefEffect((element) => {
    var msnry;

    const { ownerDocument } = element;
    const { defaultView } = ownerDocument;

    if (!defaultView.Masonry) {
        return;
    }

    msnry = new defaultView.Masonry(element, {
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        percentPosition: true,
        gutter: parseInt(gap),
    });

    return () => {
        msnry?.destroy();
    }

}, [items, columns, gap, crop, captions]);
```

My problem is that on the first render, `defaultView.Masonry` is not yet available so the function returns, and the Masonry instance is not created, unless some of the attributes in the dependency array change. My question is: is there a way to re-render the component when `defaultView.Masonry` is finally available?

**block.json:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 3,
    "name": "my/masonry-grid",
    "title": "Masonry gallery",
    "description": "Display a masonry gallery.",
    "category": "media",
    "attributes": {
        "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": []
        },
        "columns": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 1,
            "maximum": 8,
            "default": 3
        },
        "gap": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "10px"
        },
        "crop": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        },
        "captions": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": false
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "spacing": {
            "margin": true,
            "padding": true
        },
        "align": [ "center" ]
    },
    "script": [
        "imagesloaded",
        "masonry"
    ],
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "viewScript": "file:./view.js",
    "style": [
        "file:./style-index.css",
        "file:./view.css"
    ],
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css"
}
```

**Example screenshots:**

On first render, Masonry is not yet available and is not initalized and the image gallery is shown as a regular grid:

[image]

Once a block attribute is changed, `useRefEffect()` is called again because one of the vars in its dependency array has changed and, by then, Masonry is already available and is initialized:

[image]

Comment: If you're just trying to fix the "return" issue, then maybe you can just use a local state? E.g. In the edit function, add `const [ masonryLoaded, setMasonryLoaded ] = useState( false );`, then in the ref callback, do `if (!defaultView.Masonry) { setMasonryLoaded( false ); return; } setMasonryLoaded( true );`. Then add `masonryLoaded` as a dependency for that callback - `[items, ..., masonryLoaded]`. That should trigger the component's render when `masonryLoaded` becomes a true, but I'm not sure if that should be done, i.e. are you sure Masonry isn't yet available on the 1st render?

Comment: I put `console.log('before check');` before the `if (!defaultView.Masonry) { return; }` and `console.log('after check');` after it and on the first render I only see the `before check` string in the console.

Comment: In that case, you can try what I suggested and see if doing so helps? However, it should not be an issue if `defaultView.Masonry` is not yet available when the *ref callback* is called on the first render, because it will be called again and by then, Masonry would now be available. Or am I not understanding your question? What's the problem with the "*the function returns*" and/or "*the Masonry instance is not created*"? Maybe you can make it clear via some screenshots?

Comment: I added some example screenshots to my question.

Comment: Thank you. That kind of issue was what I had in mind, but it did not happen in my case and thus, I asked for a clarification. Can I see your full source on GitHub, so that I can hopefully give a better suggestion?

Comment: The issue still did not happen in my case even when I deliberately set the Masonry script to be loaded *after* my block scripts, so I really wondered what's in your code which is causing the issue. And although there is a workaround for that, I'd rather check your code first.

Comment: Yes, it's strange. Let me check my code to see if I'm doing something incorrectly. I'll come back to you later.

Comment: So, have you resolved the issue? What did you do?

Comment: Sorry for coming back at you so late. If you want to check out my code, I uploaded it to GitHub: https://github.com/mrleemon/test-masonry (You can ignore the /assets directory as it's not relevant to my issue)

Answer (score 1):

`wp_add_inline_script` can be used to insert a tiny trigger script that executes after the script specified in `script` and any instance defined by that script will be available.

```php
// When this js executes `Masonry` is sure to be defined
wp_add_inline_script( 'masonry', 'if (window.top !== window) doItNow()');
```

This will end up being executed twice when the editor is iframed because scripts specified with `script` are loaded in both windows/documents. That’s the reason to conditionally `doItNow()` only when the window isn’t the topmost.

Then to have a component re-render, the trigger should update [a store](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#registering-a-store) that the component [subscribes](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#useselect) to and the variable holding the value from the store has be included in the `useRefEffect` dependencies.

---

I've published a [git repo](https://github.com/stokesman/demo-wp-masonry-block/) of a working demonstration. It’s pretty bare-bones and doesn't require a build step so hopefully it’s easy enough to dissect. The quickest way to test is running [`wp-now start`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wp-now/wp-now#usage) from the directory.

I can extract and explain some key parts of the code here if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You should include it in your dependencies here:

```
}, [items, columns, gap, crop, captions]);
```

The function will run whenever the hooks dependencies change, so pass in the thing it depends on, or the result of a check to see if it has been loaded. Add a check in the function that gets called so it only runs if it's set though.

As a sidenote, declare Masonry as a dependency of your built script when its enqueued so that it's loaded beforehand. This should minimise the issue, but you'll still need to declare it as a dependency of the `useRefEffect` hook.

Comment: How can I import the Masonry lib (vanilla JS) that is included in WordPress? I don't want to add an external lib via npm.

Comment: if you were using the WP Scripts then it would have automatically seen that masonry is included with WP and put masonry in the list of dependencies when `wp_enqueue_script` was called to guarantee it was loaded before your script, then ensured that even with an `import` statement the library didn't get put in your built assets. This is how blocks can be in tiny built asset files and distributed without ending up with massive bundles that contain half of the `@wordpress/` packages, it swaps them out for references when built, e.g. `@wordpress/components` becomes `window.wp.components` etc

Comment: Few things here. WP Scripts doesn’t externalize all of WP’s included js libraries. It’s a short list besides the `@wordress/*` ones and Masonry is not in it. It may be possible to configure it such that it would but I don't know the details of that. Anyway, even were the library externalized from the build and loaded before the block’s script then you’d be back to square one on this problem. The scripts (like Masonry) that load in the editor’s iframe execute well after those (like the block’s) that load in the root document.

Comment: you can adjust webpack configuration to add masonry as an external, which is how WP Scripts does it for the WP packages, but even then it should be declared as a dependency regardless of the order in order to help mitigate that issue. Fundamentally declaring it as a dependency of `useRefEffect` along with the others is the real fix

Comment: I agree that technically it’s a dependency yet it functionally won’t matter in this case because the masonry script in the editor’s iframe will never execute before the block’s script in the root window.

Indeed the key here is `useRefEffect` needs to rerun once `Masonry` is defined. It’s the main thrust of your answer but it’s important to point out a global will do nothing in an effect’s dependencies. Instead, it has to be a variable that’s  "the result of a check to see if it has been loaded" (as mentioned in your answer). A result one has to get via a polling loop or doing as my answer.